# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies on EJB project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, cdi, glassfish-4, weld

I have an multi-module maven project with three projects. First ejb project with shared data `test-base`. A second ejb project `test-timer` which should be deployed on a glassfish 4.x application server to run periodic tasks (`@Scheduel`) and depend on `test-base`. And finally a third war project `test-webapp` with simple webapp which also depend on `test-base` and is also going to be separately deployed to glassfish 4.x application server.
In the `test-base` project is a CDI bean. The poject contains beans.xml.

`test-webapp` works like a charm. But if I try to deploy `test-timer` I get a deployment exception.

> `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MyCdiBean] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.test.MyTimer.bean]`

After searching the net (i. e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191377/cdi-weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependencies-how-to-resolve-it) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899920/glassfish-4-simple-example-in-cdi-fails-with-weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependenci)), I thought it has something to do with the `beans.xml`. `test-base` contains a `beans.xml` and webapp is running just fine. As with `test-timer` it makes no difference whether I have a `beans.xml` or not.

`beans.xml` is generated by netbeans ide and looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

I also tried to change the `bean-discovery-mode="all"` both in `test-base` and `test-timer` but nothing changed.

Here is my project structure.

```
test-parent
|--test-base
   |--src
      |--main
         |--java
            |--org/test/MyCdiBean.java
         |--resources
            |--META-INF
               |--beans.xml
      |--test
   |--pom.xml
|--test-timer
   |--src
      |--main
         |--java
            |--org/test/MyTimer.java
         |--resources
            |--META-INF
               |--beans.xml
      |--test
   |--pom.xml
|--test-webapp
   |--src
      |--main
         |--java
            |--org/test/WebAppBean.java
         |--resources
            |--META-INF
               |--beans.xml
         |--webapp
            |--WEB-INF
               |--web.xml
            |--index.xhtml
      |--test
   |--pom.xml
|--pom.xml
```

Any hints on what I am doing wrong are appreciated.

I can attach source if necessary.

**EDIT** Additional information as requested in comment.

New `beans.xml` is now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

Still does not work.

I am using WELD Version `WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1)` and also tested it with `WELD-000900: 2.2.13 (Final)`

MyCdiBean.java in `test-base`

```
@javax.inject.Named 
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped 
//@javax.enterprise.context.Dependent /* also tried with  */
public class MyCdiBean {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, on the `beans.xml`, the new javaee namespace id `xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"`

Can you also tell us what is the CDI/Weld version you are using? The code for the bean annotation may also be helpful

Comment: @maress  Thanks for quick response. I have enhanced the question with additional information.

Comment: Somehow, weld is not scanning your `test-base` for beans, which is weird..